# Open custom IE window from Flex or Can a window customize itself?

Tags: php, javascript, html, apache-flex

Is it possible to open a custom IE window (i.e no status bar or address bar etc) from within flex? or if i call a php file or html file can the page customize itself when loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript inside the HTML page that the Flex application resides..

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function images(url) 
{
 var width  = 700;
 var height = 500;
 var left   = (screen.width  - width)/2;
 var top    = (screen.height - height)/2;
 var params = 'width='+width+', height='+height;
 params += ', top='+top+', left='+left;
 params += ', directories=no';
 params += ', location=no';
 params += ', menubar=no';
 params += ', resizable=no';
 params += ', scrollbars=no';
 params += ', status=no';
 params += ', toolbar=no';
 newwin=window.open(url,'Screenshots', params);
 if (window.focus) {newwin.focus()}
 return false;
}
</script>
```

And the flex function called when the button is clicked...

```
private function imagesButtonClick():void {
    var url:String = data.images;
    ExternalInterface.call("images", url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call a php or html file using HTTPService.

```
import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService


<mx:HTTPService method="post" url="{php path}" resultFormat="e4x" ShowBusyCursor="true" />
```

php or html

```
<?php

echo "<script>window.open('url path','mywindow','width=400,height=200,scrollbars=no, toolbar=no,menubar=no')</script>";


?>
```

Please check for minor error.

Hope this help

Comment: Hi Treby, i am not quite sure how a POST method to a PHP file would work... that php code called in a browser works but not in the Flex code. I have done further research and believe i should be able to put javascript into the Flex using the ExternalInterface function but not sure on that either.

Comment: you can disregard the method="post" just put the url path either php or html. while in the html side, u just put the code in 
<body onload="window.open('url path','mywindow','width=400,height=200,scrollbars=no, toolbar=no,menubar=no')" >